# How do huge databases handle new users?

Tags: performance, database-design

My question is on database design. How do you design a schema for DBs with a humongous number of rows? For example access logs: you can create a table **access(date, user, endpoint)** but for systems with a lot of users, this would result in a table with an unusable number of rows quickly.

As a solution, my idea would be to create a set of tables for each new user: in our model case just **access_user_1001(...)**. This would scale horizontally with the growth of the number of users.

Is this approach used at all, or is it better to just deal with huge tables somehow?

Comment: Define "humongous".  I know one poster that handles more than 1 Billion rows per day.

Comment: @MichaelKutz that's about the scale I had in mind. Or even one or two orders of magnitude larger. I just want to hear from people how it's commonly solved.

Comment: For any non-trivial problem there is no "commonly used" solution, each one is bespoke and fit for its particular conditions.

Comment: @mustaccio cool. Can you please share one of those bespoke solutions?

Comment: Do you really have to use a relational database or is it possible for you to use a NoSQL solution. Here is a thread that discusses a possible similar scenario as yours.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525725/which-nosql-database-should-i-use-for-logging

Comment: database structures like tables, indexes etc are designed to handle huge amount of data. If you implement your concept, then you have he same amount of data but now two additionally components are involved in handling this big amount of data, the self-knitted application code to handle a huge amount of data and the database metadata repository, Both of these components are not specialized to handle a large mount of data. So no, it is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Pretty much all database implement partitioning: the ability to automatically split “humongous” tables in large numbers of storage units (partitions) based on a variety or criteria. In your case a simple scheme is to partition by date: each partition holds accesses for one day. Or one hour. Or a week. Partitions can be merged to form larger partitions. Or maybe partition by user. Or endpoint. Or a combination ...

Comment: Partitioning by date is good for managing the lifecycle of the data - something you do not seem to consider: for how long do you keep this access log data ? One year ? 5 years ? Partitioning makes it easy to store older date on high-capacity low-performing drives and keep newer date on high-speed SSDs. 

You also do not say how that data will be used. Why do you keep it. For how long ... Storage in itself is not difficult and size is not important, but you cannot design it without considering usage and life cycle.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind excellent points, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Partition

The concept you have envisioned has already been implemented by various databases under the feature called `PARTITION`.

The difference is: all those small tables (partitions) look and feel like a single table to your application.

The function that describes "Which Table do I put the data in?" is defined at the `CREATE TABLE` time.  The data is partitioned based on Partition Keys (value of data in a column(s)).  (RDBMS dependant) You can partition the data by a Range, List of values, or the result of a hashing function.  Some RDBMS can automatically create the partition for you (eg Oracle's interval partition) as you need it.

From my experience, most of the time, partitioning is done on the value of some `DATE` column.  This way, large chunks of data can be removed from the DB "in a blink of an eye" (according to your Legal Department's requirements)

## Do you need to use `PARTITION` for large data?

It depends.

In some cases, YES.  In other cases, NO.

If your query can take advantage of Partition Pruning (looks at only a handful of the small tables based on your `WHERE` clause), then Partitions might work for you.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I guess I have some reading to do on partitioning.